# DocumentRootの変更に伴うエラー

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

XAMPPを使ってphpを学び始めました。windows10を使っております。
詰まってしまったので教えていただけると助かります。

C:/xampp/htdocs/httpd.confファイルの中にあるDocumentRootの`"C:/xampp/htdocs"`の部分を`"C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php"`に変更し、XAMPPのコントロールパネルの方で、Apacheのstartボタンを押したところ、以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示されました。

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked
>   port, missing dependencies,  improper privileges, a crash, or a
>   shutdown by another method. Press the Logs button to view error logs
>   and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues If you need more
>   help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums

いちばん最初にDocumentRootを`"C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php"`に変更したときは、エラーメッセージは表示されず、Apacheは起動しました。自分が何かいじってしまったのでしょうか？

なお、DocumentRootが`"C:/xampp/htdocs"`の場合だと、Apacheは起動し、index.phpの内容はブラウザに表示されます。

DocumentRootの変更には何をする必要があるのでしょうか？
初心者の質問で分かりにくいかもですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

【追加情報】

参考になるか分かりませんが、`C:/xampp/htdocs/httpd.conf`でサーバーネームとポートは以下の様に設定されています。

```
ServerName localhost:80
Listen 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentRootには**ディレクトリ** (フォルダ)を指定する必要があります。index.phpがファイル名であるなら、指定が間違っています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ググってみたところ、コマンドプロンプトを使ってhttpd.conf内のエラーを探せるという情報があったため、指示通りやってみたところ、やはりDocumentRootの記述がおかしかったみたいです。とりあえずは解決いたしました。お手数おかけしましたm(__)m

Comment: 解決したようでなによりです。なお「回答」はあくまで「質問に対する」回答を行う場所なので、単なる返事を書きたい場合には「コメント」を使いましょう。(今回はこちらでコメントに移行させて頂きました)